# Can a dependent clause undergo inversion in English?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The grammars I've seen state that dependent clauses never undergo inversion. This agrees with sentences like

> *Tell me where he is.*

But how sentences like

> *Tell me, where is he?*

should be analyzed? Isn't *where is he* a dependent clause in this case?

Comment: By "inversion", do you mean _Subject-Auxiliary Inversion_? And -- alas -- most grammars are really, really, terrible when it comes to rules like this. They're almost never correct, and they never deal with exceptions. You shouldn't trust them. Sorry.

Comment: This should probably be moved to ELU.SE.

Comment: I wouldn't otherwise point this out, but since it has some relevance, you'd probably want to know. It should be "But how should sentences like [...] be analyzed?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Where is he" is an independent clause. The subject-verb inversion is because it's an interrogatory independent clause. There wouldn't be a question mark if it were a dependent clause, since the main clause would be imperative. The sentence has two independent clauses without a conjunction. In most cases this would call for a semicolon, but when the first clause is a short imperative one introducing a question, a comma is used. A well-known complicated example is found in the US national anthem: "Oh say, can you see by the dawn's early light ..." and so on through a labyrinth of subordinate clauses.

Answer (score -1):

I'd write it with a colon:

> Tell me: where is he?

I would consider the *tell me* as a way for the speaker to introduce a question.  Similar to how we use *so* to indicate a change of topic. (I forget the grammatical term.)